# time compare showing wrong result using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have following mysql table

```
id      shopid      date            starttime       end_time
1       1           2019-08-08      09:10           10:12
2       1           2019-08-08      14:10           15:15
```

i want to compare with my dynamic "start_time" and "end_time",but my current result is wrong
i want if user send "start" and "end" time which not between database saved time , then record should insert
otherwise showing "time exist" message,I Tried with following code

```
foreach($rows as $rw)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    echo "req time is".$_POST['start_time'];
    $your_date = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($add_data['service_date']));
    $req_stime = strtotime( $your_date." ".$_POST['start_time']);
    $req_etime = strtotime( $your_date." ".$_POST['end_time']);
    $bookedstime = strtotime( $rw['services_dates']." ".$rw['start_time']);
    $bookedetime = strtotime( $rw['services_dates']." ".$rw['end_time']);

    if(($req_stime>=$bookedstime || $req_stime<=$bookedetime) || ($req_etime>=$bookedstime && $req_etime<=$bookedetime))
    {
        echo "exist";
    }
    else
    {
        //insert query
    }
}
```

Comment: Give a proper example of what values you are POSTing for start_time and end_time. And please explain what you have done so far to debug this. Have you _verified_ that these variables all contain what you assume they should, that strtotime was able to parse the values you supplied correctly …?

Comment: @misorude: i am passing start_time  "13:05" and end_time="15:50" but its showing "exist"

Comment: @misorude: i checked , all the variables are correct

Comment: What is `$add_data['service_date']`, is that just supposed to be `2019-08-08` as well?

Comment: If so, `2019-08-08 13:05` is greater than `2019-08-08 09:10`, so the very first of the conditions you are checking there is already true for the first record.

Comment: @misorude: you are right,$add_data['service_date'] = 2019-08-08 , i just want to check mysql , if time availiable ( not come between saved (start or end time)),then new record should inserted otherwise "time not aviliable" message should display

Comment: It's always nice to see the query

Comment: _“if time availiable ( not come between saved (start or end time))”_ - that alone does not mean available - it could start before and end after one of the entries you have already stored. // You apparently have a problem figuring out the basic comparison logic here, so I would advise you to get a piece of paper, and simply _“draw”_ the different scenarios you have to cover (a simply line, mark start and end on it, …) - that should make it easier to figure out which conditions you actually need.